# Trouble installing angular material

Tags: angular, installation, angular-material

I followed the simple instructions.

Installed the two packages

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.4"
}
```

Added to *app.shared.modules.ts*

```
import { MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material';
```

and

```
import: [   MatButtonModule,
        MatCheckboxModule]
```

Added import to *app.component.css*

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

And when I try to run I get

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Cannot find module "rxjs/operators/take"
>   at webpackMissingModule (C:\Users\MHerb\Downloads\AAMC RET\Aamc\Aamc\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:17786:139)

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using the last version of @angular/cli ?

Comment: Did you try npm install --save rxjs@latest?